# issue following / unfollowing users when searched for? Parse

Tags: ios, swift

Good Afternoon,

Today I am having some issues with parse.

I have created a UISearchController, loaded my users from parse so I can search for individual ones and I have added a following and unfollowing feature.

My Problem is when I search for a specific user and try to follow him: So I search for a specific user say "test" it shows up as it should, but when I click follow and then go back to parse to see if "I" have followed test I can a different result.

It says I have followed for example "tester" which was the first user created. Its seeming to follow the Cell and now the userId...

After that I manged to get the users in alphabetical order, but same problem here except it follows the first user in alphabetical order for example if I have a username that begins with an "A"!

I'm not sure how to fix this issue, so I'm hoping someone here does..I accept and appreciate all kind of tips and answers!

Heres my code:

```
class yahTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var users: [PFUser] = [PFUser]()
    var followingList: [PFUser] = [PFUser]()
    var searchResults: Bool = false

    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
    var refresher: UIRefreshControl!
    @IBOutlet var userTableView: UITableView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
            self.resultSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
            self.navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController.searchBar
            self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            self.definesPresentationContext = true
            self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            self.resultSearchController.searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
            self.resultSearchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()



            for subview in self.resultSearchController.searchBar.subviews

            {for subsubView in subview.subviews
            {if let textField = subsubView as? UITextField
            {textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("Search", comment: ""), attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])
                textField.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                }}}


            tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
            self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 15, bottom: 10, right: 15)


            refresher = UIRefreshControl()

            refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "")

            refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

            self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)




        }





    //Function used to load the users on first view load or when the UI refresh is performed
    private func loadUsers(searchString: String){

      func refresh() {

        let query = PFUser.query()
        query!.whereKey("username", containsString: searchString )

        self.searchResults = true

    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil) {
                self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                self.users += objects as! [PFUser]
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                print("search query error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }


                // Now get the following data for the current user
                let query = PFQuery(className: "followers")
                query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)

                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
                    if  (error == nil) {
                        self.followingList.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                        self.followingList += objects as! [PFUser]
                        self.userTableView.reloadData()
                    } else
                        if error != nil {
                        print("Error getting following: \(error) \(error!.userInfo)")
                    }
                })
                 }


            self.searchResults = false

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refresher.endRefreshing()
        }}








    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        // Force search if user pushes button
        let searchString: String = searchBar.text!.lowercaseString
        if (searchString != "") {
            loadUsers(searchString)
        }
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {


        searchBar.text = ""


    }



    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

        let searchString: String = searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString
        if (searchString != "" && !self.searchResults) {
            loadUsers(searchString)
        }
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
            return self.users.count
        } else {
            return self.users.count
            // return whatever your normal data source is
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")! as UITableViewCell

        if (self.resultSearchController.active && self.users.count > indexPath.row) {
            let userObject = users[indexPath.row]
            Cell.textLabel?.text = userObject.username

            for following in followingList {
                if following["following"] as? String == PFUser.currentUser()! {
                    //Add checkbox to cell
                    Cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
                    break
                }}

            // bind data to the search results cell
        } else {

            // bind data from your normal data source
        }

        return Cell
    }



    // MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if let selectedUser = users[indexPath.row] as? PFUser {
            // Now get the following/following data for the current user
            let query = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
            query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!)
            query.whereKey("following", equalTo: (selectedUser.objectId)!)

            query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil && object == nil {
                    // Means the record doesn't exist
                    self.insertFollowingRecord(selectedUser, selectedIndexPath: indexPath)
                } else {


                    // Means record is present, so we will delete it
                    if let followingObject = object {
                        followingObject.deleteInBackground()

                        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.userTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
                        //Remove checkbox from cell
                        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

    private func insertFollowingRecord (selectedUser:PFUser, selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Void {
        // Now add the data for following in parse
        let following:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Followers")
        following["following"] = selectedUser.objectId
        following["follower"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId

        following.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
            if success {
                let cell:UITableViewCell = self.userTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath)!
                //Add checkbox to cell
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
            } else if error != nil {
                print("Error getting following: \(error) \(error!.userInfo)")
            }
        })
}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to implement the `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol to achieve this. It uses a `UISearchController` (introduced in iOS 8) which has to be added programmatically instead of through the storyboard, but don't worry, it's pretty straight-forward.

This should get the job done for you

Courtesy of Russel.

```
class YourTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    var searchUsers: [PFUser] = [PFUser]()
    var userSearchController = UISearchController()
    var searchActive: Bool = false

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.userSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.userSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

        // This is used for dynamic search results updating while the user types
        // Requires UISearchResultsUpdating delegate
        self.userSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        // Configure the search controller's search bar
        self.userSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for a user"
        self.userSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.userSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.definesPresentationContext = true

        // Set the search controller to the header of the table
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.userSearchController.searchBar
    }

    // MARK: - Parse Backend methods

    func loadSearchUsers(searchString: String) {
        var query = PFUser.query()

        // Filter by search string
        query.whereKey("username", containsString: searchString)

        self.searchActive = true
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if (error == nil) {
                self.searchUsers.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                self.searchUsers += objects as! [PFUser]
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("search query error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }
            self.searchActive = false
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Search Bar Delegate Methods

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        // Force search if user pushes button
        let searchString: String = searchBar.text.lowercaseString
        if (searchString != "") {
            loadSearchUsers(searchString)
        }
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        // Clear any search criteria
        searchBar.text = ""

        // Force reload of table data from normal data source
    }

    // MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Methods

    // This function is used along with UISearchResultsUpdating for dynamic search results processing
    // Called anytime the search bar text is changed
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

        let searchString: String = searchController.searchBar.text.lowercaseString
        if (searchString != "" && !self.searchActive) {
            loadSearchUsers(searchString)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (self.userSearchController.active) {
            return self.searchUsers.count
        } else {
            // return whatever your normal data source is
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userCell") as! UserCell

        if (self.userSearchController.active && self.searchUsers.count > indexPath.row) {
            // bind data to the search results cell
        } else {
            // bind data from your normal data source
        }

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        if (self.userSearchController.active && self.searchUsers.count > 0) {
            // Segue or whatever you want
        } else {
            // normal data source selection
        }
    }
}
```